# Push object to array in js or jquery?

Tags: jquery

In my `Script.js` I am trying to push the object to array=>array of objects.

```
$("#save_filter").click(function(){
    var filter_saved = new Object();//Create new object to store the filter have been saved.
    var customer_type_selected = $('#id_customer_type :selected').text();
    var list_tag_selected = $("#tag_checked").val();
    var filter_name = $("#put_filter_name").val();

    // Save filter name to the object={tag:[2,3,], customer_type:'TDO', more...}
    filter_saved = {
        customer_type: customer_type_selected,
        tag: list_tag_selected
    };
    var array_obj_filter_saved = []

    //I am trying...
    array_obj_filter_saved.push(filter_saved);//push every objects to array
    alert(array_obj_filter_saved.length);
});
```

My Array will be like this  assciated array

```
array_obj_filter_saved = {"time1":filter_saved1,"time2":filter_saved2}
```

Anybody know how can I push every object to a array or associated array?

*** filter_saved this an object  it will create every time base on options in   form(customer_type_selected(choicefield),list_tag_selected(checkboxs))

Comment: Sorry for unclear quiz :What I want is array_obj_filter_saved.push(filter_saved);//push every objects to array
so my array_obj_filter_saved = [object_saved1,object_saved2,...]
Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line below is not an array, it is an object. You can only have integer indexes in arrays, and you use `[]` to define an array (like you did in your example).

```
array_obj_filter_saved = {"time1":filter_saved1,"time2":filter_saved2}
```

You cannot push objects onto an object, instead you set them, using the specific index:

```
array_obj_filter_saved["keyName"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very unclear to me. Is `array_obj_filter_saved` an array or not?

If you want to append all the elements of an `Array` to another `Array`, you can use the `concat` method:

```
var a1 = ["a", "b", "c"], a2 = ["d", "e"];
var a3 = a1.concat(a2); // a3 is ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
var x= { a: 1};
x.b = 2;
```