# How to push array object element in object array in jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create customized product order in this I need to store all selected options store in the JSON.

like this

```
let attr = [{
        fabric: 'Bargandi Check',
        style:[{
                 Jacket lapels: 'Notch'
        }],
    }];
```

[selector image for understanding batter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pB3s.png)

I want when user select any of these options I will store in JSON when a user updates any of option it will update in the JSON object and when user select the new option it will add in JSON

like this

```
let attr = [{
        fabric: 'Bargandi Check',
        style:[{
                 Jacket lapels: 'Notch',
                 Lapel width: 'Slim' // this
        }],
    }];
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957930/14561188 hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "push" an element into a Javascript object. but you can either use the dot operator or square brackets to access an existing property / rewrite property / assign property

```js
const obj = { name: 'ed', age: '16' };

// rewriting an existing property
obj["age"] = 20; 
obj["name"] = 'edward'; 

console.log(obj["skill"]); // will be undefined
obj["skill"] = "Javascript"; // setting it as a new property

obj["list"] = []; // the list property is an array

obj["list"].push(1); // now i can use push because its an array
console.log(obj);
```

One more thing, javascript properties cannot have blank spaces, but you can seperate it with a hyphen or an underscore

> "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation" - MDN

**Your Corrected Object**

```js
let attr = [{
    fabric: 'Bargandi Check',
    style: [{
        Jacket_lapels: 'Notch',
        Lapel_width: 'Slim' // this
    }],
}];


const found = attr.find(x => x.fabric == 'Bargandi Check');
found.style[0].Lapel_width = 'Thick' // this will rewrite the width property to "thick"

console.log(attr);
```

Comment: I am very thankful to you for my helping. but I don't need it ```find(x => x.fabric == 'Bargandi Check');```

Comment: ah okay, glad to help :) please consider marking the answer as a correct one  if it helped you